# How to check nonce lifetime value of plugins?

Tags: ajax, wp-admin, nonce

Dear StackExchange users,

I currently use the premium version of WP Fastest Cache Premium. My website loads very fast, but I always get a 403 error for wp-admin/ajax.

I believe there is a plugin with a tremendously low nonce lifetime value.

Does anybody know how and where I can check the none lifetime value of my plugins.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check codex info about Nonces life time [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces#Modifying_the_nonce_lifetime).

Here is a quick code that will echo life time of nonces in footer of your site's front-end as html comment. Put it in your functions.php file.

```
$n  = "";
add_filter('nonce_life', 'wptuts_change_nonce_hourly');
function wptuts_change_nonce_hourly( $nonce_life ) {
    global $n ;
    $n = $nonce_life;
    return $nonce_life;
}

// Display in footer comments
add_filter("wp_footer","d");
function d(){
    global $n;
    echo "<!- Nonce Life =". $n ."-->";
}
```

**NOTE**: This code does not give the ideal way to check life time of nonce, but a quick fix to get the desired info. You should delete this code from functions.php once you get the info.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried that, unfortunately I didn't see the lifetime values in my footer. I use the Hestia theme. Could this be a reason why I can't view the data?

Comment: Since it is wrapped in an html comment tag, so it is not visible on front-end view. Right click anywhere in the page and select "View page source" and scroll down to the footer area code. You will see somethin  like <!- Nonce Life =8640-->